# azure-pipeline-task with different user context

Tags: azure-pipelines, ntlm-authentication

**Question:**

Is it possible to execute an azure-pipeline-task with different user context?

**Background:**

In my azure devops pipeline I want to execute acceptance-tests in separate pipeline tasks with different user contexts. (e.g. call API endpoint A with admin-user/power-user/regular-user,...)

Three ways come to my mind to possibly achieve that:

1. **System.Net.NetworkCredential** Class (create different
   HttpClientHandler per user)
2. **http proxy** (use different
   proxies that act as users to handle NTLM authentication)
3. **azure-pipeline-task** with different user context (don't know if it is possible)

Comment: Are you using onprem agents or ADO's hosted ones?

Comment: What's the detail requirement that you need to use different user? Do you call API in tests with that user (authentication)? Is this user in your DevOps organization? If not, please provide the details of that user. On the other hand, you said "separate pipeline tasks", is this task in same pipeline or in different pipeline? Which agent you used? Hosted or private?